# I am getting error when i run simple code in pandas using jupyter

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('‪C:\\Users\\sudarshan\\Downloads\\bulk.csv')
```

I am getting the below error message when i try to read the csv file please help,

This is very simple code but i am not understanding why i got this error message below is the error message

```
 OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b4623e74f1e6> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df4 = pd.read_csv('‪C:\\Users\\sudarshan\\Downloads\\bulk.csv')
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\\Users\\sudarshan\\Downloads\\bulk.csv'
```

Comment: Pandas can't open file `'\u202aC:\\Users\\sudarshan\\Downloads\\bulk.csv'`. You have a special character before `C:`. The character is 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING'

Comment: There are some invisble control characters in the path. Try to input the path manually by typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an r in front of your path like so. ==>`pd.read_csv(r'‪C:\\Users\\sudarshan\\Downloads\\bulk.csv')` <==

If this doesn't work then check your C:Drive to see if one drive or sync is on. Due to the constant sync running in the background it interferes with exports.

Let me know if that works for you!!!

Comment: I've also found that if you move your csv into the root directory for example ==>C:\bulk.csv<== it works (It must have something to do with folder security) !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).